# Excel VBA code not running using F5 only F8

Tags: excel, vba

This is my VBA code below, it executes when running with F8 but when running it with F5. it doesn't give any error or anything, it just doesn't run.

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = 0
LastColumn = 0

LastRow = ws.Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws.Cells(11, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
delay 60
Range("A1").Select
```

I tried to delay the code for 60 seconds, maybe it runs too fast but doesn't work either. any help?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? Did you try using `Debug.Print` or a `MsgBox` to try to debug it? Side note: In general, you want to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: Have you included all of your code? e.g., Is this in a `Sub`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code with the ranges qualified back to Worksheet level:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet ' you should change this to Worksheets("YourSheetName") to be safer
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = 0
LastColumn = 0
With ws
    LastRow = .Range("c" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(12, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
    delay 60
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

This is assuming that all the ranges in question are on the same `Activesheet`.